# What is the best way to display my entities at Back-office home page with the Sonata Admin Bundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

I am doing a back-office with the SONATA ADMIN BUNDLE and I was wondering how you get your different entities in the back-office side to get all my different objects at home-page. It's could be very great to have something like the demo : http://demo.sonata-project.org/admin/dashboard.
Has someone else experienced about this and can explain me?

Comment: See dashboard section in docs and how to create a sonata block and register in dashboard

Comment: I ever did my differents blocks and know i need to match with my entities to display the differents features that i would like to have on the home-page.

Comment: If someone have an idea, i follow this tutorial to create my different block : https://sonata-project.org/bundles/block/master/doc/reference/your_first_block.html and I would to get my elements (entities) but I never used the services and Doctrine. And i would like to work in the right direction.

Comment: I am following this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966575/sonataadminbundle-display-non-crud-statistics#comment46727798_15987311 
and : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24229141/getting-instance-of-container-in-custom-sonata-block?answertab=active#tab-top.
To test it, i try with a statistic block. In my case with messages. 
So the block is in right place but now i need to inform with the exact number of messages. 
Has  someone had an example to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess you have a service defined in your services.yml. In that service you need to grab the information you want..

So you'll need some doctrine class, but your service doesn't have these.. You can inject them in your services.yml, for example:

```
sonata.block.service.statistics:
        class: Evince\ObjectsBundle\Block\Service\StatisticsService
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.block }

        arguments:
            - ~
            - '@templating'
        calls:       
            - [ setDoctrine, ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]] # <- here add the doctrine entity manager
```

In your service you have to implement an 'setDoctrine' function:

```
private $doctrine;
/**
 * @param mixed $doctrine
 */
public function setDoctrine($doctrine)
{
    $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
}
```

And a getDoctrine function:

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getDoctrine()
{
    return $this->doctrine;
}
```

Now, when symfony builds your service when you need it, it will inject the doctrine entity manager for you.. This is called 'Dependency Indjection'.

In the execute function you can do something like this:

```
$repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeYourBundle:YourEntityClass');
$query = $repo->createQueryBuilder()
          ->from('foo', 'f')
          ->where('foo.bar = :id')
          ->setParameter('id', $someId)
          ->getQuery();
$results = $query->getResult();
$resultCount = count($results);

//-> pass the resultCount to your template
```

See the symfony website for information how to use doctrine.