# Is there a way for a block service to get the page ID from which it is being called?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, sonata, symfony-3.3

In my Symfony 3.3 application, I have built a block service using SonataBlockBundle. Now I want to pull some other field values from the page on which the block lives. In other words, I want to do something like this:

```
public function configureSettings(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $pageRepository = $this->doctrine->getRepository('ApplicationSonataPageBundle:Page');

    $pageId = someMagicalMethodCall();

    $page = $repository->findOneBy(['id' => $pageId]);
    $images = $page->getImageUrls;
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'content' => 'Some custom content',
        'images' => $images,
        'template' => 'AppBundle:Block:block_media.html.twig',
    ));
}
```

Is this possible? If so, what would I put in place of `someMagicalMethodCall` in the block above?

Comment: what platform / framework are you using here?

Comment: Good question, Josh. After seeing your comment, I have edited the question to include that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jakub Krawczyk and a mentor, I found this page:

[Getting instance of container in custom sonata block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24229141/getting-instance-of-container-in-custom-sonata-block)

... which led me to another way of getting the page related to a block, from within the execute() method. So I now have the following code, which serves me well:

```
public function execute(BlockContextInterface $blockContext, Response $response = null)
{
    $page = $blockContext->getBlock()->getPage();
    $localImages = $page->getImages();
    $imageProvider = $this->provider;
    foreach ($localImages as $key => $image) {
        $publicImages[$key]['url'] = $imageProvider->generatePublicUrl($image, 'reference');
        $publicImages[$key]['name'] = $image->getName();
    }
    $settings = $blockContext->getSettings();
    $settings['images'] = $publicImages;
    return $this->renderResponse($blockContext->getTemplate(), array(
        'block' => $blockContext->getBlock(),
        'settings' => $settings,
    ), $response);
}
```

Again, thanks to all involved.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but you need to inject additional service in your block -  `CmsManagerSelector`. Then in your `configureSettings` you need to retrieve the proper manager and get the current page instance from it. For example in your code:

```
public function configureSettings(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $cmsManager = $this->cmsManagerSelector->retrieve();
    // $page will be the Page object already, no need to call doctrine repository. Reference: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataPageBundle/blob/3.x/src/CmsManager/BaseCmsPageManager.php#L38
    $page = $cmsManager->getCurrentPage();

    $images = $page->getImageUrls;
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'content' => 'Some custom content',
        'images' => $images,
        'template' => 'AppBundle:Block:block_media.html.twig',
    ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I just tried injecting @CmsManagerSelector in admin.yml and got a ServiceNotFoundException. Is there another name that this object lives under?

Comment: @Patrickatwork if you are using autowiring, then you can simply provide the `CmsManagerSelectorInterface` typehint in the constructor. If not, I believe that `sonata.page.cms_manager_selector` is the right service name.

Comment: It looks like it's maybe mostly working, but for some reason, calling $page->getImages() is giving me `Call to a member function getImages() on null.` So it looks like the application is having some trouble finding the page.

Comment: And you are sure that there is a snapshot of your page saved? Is `$cmsManager->getCurrentPage();` returning null or did you perform some operations after it?

Comment: It's definitely returning null, since the call to the member function is on the next line and it is not used after that.

Comment: Is the configuration correct? Did you clear the cache. I've double-checked my project and also verified that the same approach is used in the SonataPageBundle itself - https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataPageBundle/blob/2.x/Block/BreadcrumbBlockService.php .

Comment: The interesting thing is that the exception only gets thrown during attempts at inline editing/removal actions on the backend. On the front end, everything shows up just fine.

Comment: Do you need to set it in `configureSettings()`? Maybe it would be good idea to move this into the `buildEditForm()`. Then you'd have access to the `BlockInterface` with `getPage()` method, used like in here: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataPageBundle/blob/3.x/src/Block/ChildrenPagesBlockService.php#L111